# 2 dropdown and 1 search filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

Hi  I need to have 2 selectlist and 1 search field, to filter data in a index view.

I have this code from MVC4, with 1 dropdown and 1 search function, but i cannot make it Work with one more dropdown.

Can you help me in the right direction?

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string ChainSupplier, string searchString, string city)
{

    var SupplierLst = new List<string>();

    var SupplierQry = from d in db.DAT_SupplyChains
                   orderby d.Supplier
                   select d.Supplier;
    SupplierLst.AddRange(SupplierQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.ChainSupplier = new SelectList(SupplierLst);

    var cityLst = new List<string>();

    var cityQry = from d in db.SUP_Cities
                      orderby d.Name
                      select d.Name;
    cityLst.AddRange(cityQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.city = new SelectList(cityLst);

    var Supplys = from m in db.DAT_SupplyChains
                 select m;



    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        Supplys = Supplys.Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChainSupplier))
    {
        Supplys = Supplys.Where(x => x.Supplier == ChainSupplier);


        return View(Supplys);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(Supplys.Where(x => x.SUP_City.Name == city));
    }
```

Regards and tks

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            Supplys = Supplys.Where(s => s.CompanyName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChainSupplier))
        {
            Supplys = Supplys.Where(x => x.Supplier == ChainSupplier);

        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(city))

        {
            return View(Supplys.Where(x => x.SUP_City.Name == city));
        }

        return View(Supplys);

    }
```